# SQL invalid syntax for insert in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Trying to write a test trigger, but there is apparently a syntax error.

My SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_TRIGGER_TEST] 
ON [dbo].[CP_TEST] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO CP_CHECK (CHECK) VALUES ('Y');
END
GO
```

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TR_TRIGGER_TEST, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'.

I have tried formatting it a few different ways but have not found the golden ticket. Any suggestions? The `CP_CHECK` table has columns `ID`, `CHECK`, `updated_at`, and `created_at`.

Comment: CHECK is a reserved keyword. Better use some other identifier (or less preferably escape it using `[]`)

Comment: Add brackets `[]` around `Check`. It's a reserved word.

Comment: Another point to this trigger... you may want to only insert the `Y` on the `inserted` row.

Comment: I was unaware of the CHECK keyword and have changed it to 'Is_In'. The same error persists.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Check out [this list of **reserved keywords** in T-SQL / SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) - you should **definitely avoid** using any of those for your database, table, column or other names!

Comment: Excellent. This is the same SQL we are using - Microsoft SQL 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the statement as

```
CP_CHECK (`CHECK`) VALUES ('Y');
```

CHECK being a keyword is reserved, so you need to escape it somehow.

**--EDIT--**
As pointed out by @GurV, since its SQL Server, you can use square brackets `[]` to escape the keyword `CHECK` like

```
CP_CHECK ([CHECK]) VALUES ('Y');
```

Comment: It's not mysql .